# How can count columns according a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count when state = 0 And when state = 1 and when show 0 if the other state doesn't have value.

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 2                   1             0
   3      BILL                  3                   2             1
   4      LARRY                 4                   2             1

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         2 
     2     ROB          1
     3     SECURE       2
     4     ACCIDENT     1

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      BANK
    2      HOSPITAL

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      SPRINT
    2      APPLE
```

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54d2f/15
```

I'm trying to get states = 0,1,2 anc count if it doesn't exist or show 0

```
Select p.id, p.client, 
  pb.name as BUSINESS_UNITS,
  ce.name as CIA,ca.name as COMERCIAL_AREAS,
  count(p.state) as status_0,count(p.state) as status_1,count(p.state) as status_2
From policies p 
INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
```

I'm getting this result:

```
ID  CLIENT  BUSINESS_UNITS      CIA      COMERCIAL_AREAS    STATE_0 STATE_1   STATUS_2
 1  MATT    LIFE             SPRINT       HOSPITAL                4    4           4
```

I'm trying to count if state = 0,1,2 else show 0 in the state where doesn't have value

How can I do to have this result?

```
ID      CLIENT      BUSINESS_UNITS      CIA        COMERCIAL_AREAS  STATE_0   STATE_1    STATE_2
 1      MATT         LIFE              SPRINT       HOSPITAL          1         0         0
 2      STEVE        ROB               SPRINT       BANK              1         0         0
 3      BILL         SECURE            APPLE        HOSPITAL          0         1         0
 4      LARRY        ACCIDENT          APPLE        BANK              0         1         0
```

Please I will appreciate all kind of help.
Thanks.

Comment: can a client be related to more than one state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick. do an if conditional. if the state = 0 then count else put in a 0
see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54d2f/26)

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.client,
    pb.name AS BUSINESS_UNITS,
    ce.name AS CIA,ca.name AS COMERCIAL_AREAS,
    IF (p.state = 0, count(p.state), 0) AS state_0,
    IF (p.state = 1, count(p.state), 0) AS state_1,
    IF (p.state = 2, count(p.state), 0) AS state_2
FROM policies p
INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
GROUP BY pb.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

---

if you want to account for null states this would be the query.. [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6666/1)

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.client,
    pb.name AS BUSINESS_UNITS,
    ce.name AS CIA,ca.name AS COMERCIAL_AREAS,
    IF (p.state = 0, count(p.state), 0) AS state_0,
    IF (p.state = 1, count(p.state), 0) AS state_1,
    IF (p.state IS NULL, count(p.id), 0) AS state_null
FROM policies p
INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
GROUP BY pb.id
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: just edited. use the edited query --- added an order by to get the correct order

Comment: anytime! the IF() statement is pretty useful :)

Comment: I have a last question for you when you wrote :"IF (p.state = 0, count(p.state), 0)"  that "0" is to show 0 when is nil right? could be another number?

Comment: that 0 is the else.. so like if p.state = 0 then put in the count of p.state else put in a 0

Comment: the if condition is like this IF(condition, then, else) separated by commas

Comment: @CarlitosMorales No this will not handle when it is nil. You need to add `OR p.state IS NULL`. See my answer for the complete SQL.

Comment: yes it will handle when its null. the condition is not met so it puts in a 0. you dont have to add the null to p.state because if its null you don't want to count it and if its in the database with other data you do. if it is null then the first condition will not be met (because its not equal to 2) and it will put in a 0

Comment: look at the sqlfiddle... unless the database is holding "null" in the place of one of the rows for state, then that OR p.state IS NULL will never be met

Comment: Yeah, but what if it IS holding `NULL`? Isn't that what he was asking for when he said "when is nil"?

Comment: no there isn't a state 2 so its nil in that sense. the only way a state would be null in this case is when a client joins and whoever gets their information doesn't get a state. but im pretty sure if its policies and commercial stuff then a state would be required

Comment: the if checks for the value of whats stored in the state column if it doesn't exist or doesn't match then a 0 is put in. hope that helps clarify what i was doin :)

Comment: You said, there isn't state 2, so why are you handling it? From his question, it seems there is state 2 and state nil as well. His data example does not show that, but he asked for it. It's confusing, but it seems he wanted to count state 2 and nil together.

Comment: in his example there isn't a state 2. but he was checking for it in the query which is why i added it, and it puts in a 0 like he requested. his quistion was `that "0" is to show 0 when is nil right? could be another number?` not sure if he means when the condition is not true or the actual value in the database is null

Comment: in any case it wouldn't make sense to have a null state and probably not a good idea, but I can add that to the query if the OP would like

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN [condition] THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0 END) AS count
FROM [your tables]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.client,
    pb.name AS BUSINESS_UNITS,
    ce.name AS CIA,ca.name AS COMERCIAL_AREAS,
    IF (p.state = 0, count(p.state), 0) AS state_0,
    IF (p.state = 1, count(p.state), 0) AS state_1,
    IF (p.state = 2 OR p.state IS NULL, count(ISNULL(p.state)), 0) AS state_2_and_null
FROM policies p
INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
INNER JOIN cia_ensures ce ON ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
GROUP BY pb.name
ORDER BY p.id;
```

If you have more states than just [**nil, 0, 1, 2**], and you want them all under the last column `state_2_and_null`, you can change the condition `p.state = 2` to `p.state > 1`.